# Разделить PDF файл на ч/б и цветные страницы

Tags: javascript, node.js

ищу способ на джаваскрипте (ноде), который позволит загружаемый файл разделить на ч/б и цветные страницы.

Comment: Задача же плёвая. Через pdf.js рендеришь каждую страницу в картинку. Потом фильтруешь их, например, используя imagemagick: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=19580&start=15

Comment: а можно и без imagemagick. Если картинка уже загружена в canvas, циклом перебираешь каждый пиксель. У черно-серо-белых цветов все три канала RGB содежат одинаковое значение. Черный #000. Серый #888. Белый #fff. Можно добавить небольшое отклонение от серого 5%-10%.

Comment: я думаю что лучше даже ghostscript

Comment: Да вот я так подумал, для ноды три модуля pdfjs + canvas + color.js будет достаточно. Pdfjs https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js canvas https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas colorjs https://github.com/Qix-/color . Ghostscript неплох, но он в разы сложнее, его даже тупо правильно собрать уходит ни один день. А те модули, перечисленные мною 100% на яваскрипт, будут работать без компиляции где угодно, хоть на Electron, хоть на Андроид.

Comment: @DiD так там же не только определить цветность страниц надо, но и разбить файл на два новых. pdf.js такого вроде бы не умеет.

Comment: @Yaant Я думалo нужны только в виде картинок. А так PDF-writer-ов полно же https://pdf-lib.js.org/